# Deleting SKNode on contact with SKPhysicsWorld Boundaries in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am looking to create a unique opening screen for an IOS app, and I would like to have a background of balls dropping to create visual interest. I am creating the balls in the didMove() function, and they are working fine, but only some of the time. I believe the frame is too large for the display, which is making the random X and Y coordinates sometimes occur outside of the screen.

```
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector.init(dx: 0, dy: -9.8)

    let sceneBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
    sceneBody.friction = 0
    self.physicsBody = sceneBody

    let minXValue: CGFloat = 0
    let maxXValue: CGFloat = self.frame.size.width

    let minYValue: CGFloat = 0
    let maxYValue: CGFloat = self.frame.size.height

    let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.4)
    let run = SKAction.run {


        let randomXNumber = (CGFloat(arc4random()).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: maxXValue)) + minXValue
        let randomYNumber = (CGFloat(arc4random()).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: maxYValue)) + minYValue

        print("Random Y Number: \(randomYNumber)")
        print("Random X Number: \(randomXNumber)")

        let ball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 20)
        ball.fillColor = SKColor(colorLiteralRed: 212.0, green: 217.0, blue: 128.0, alpha: 1)
        ball.position = CGPoint.init(x: randomXNumber, y: randomYNumber)
        ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 20)
        ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        self.addChild(ball)

    }

    self.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([wait, run])))
```

Here is my code for the random balls.

I would also like to have these balls get removed from the view when it hits the bottom of the container, in order to increase performance on all devices and not have redundant nodes.

Which function or block of code would I need to implement this concept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Setting the scene size**
In GameViewController.swift find the function viewDidLoad and add the following line right above skView.presentScene(scene)

```
scene.size  = skView.bounds.size
```

**Remove balls from view**
To remove balls from the scene you can detect when there is a collision between the edgeLoop around the scene and the balls. Then call removeFromParent on the ball.

First, change the class declaration like so:

 `class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate` 

and then add 

`physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self` in didMoveToView.

Second, above the class declaration in GameScene.swift, create the physics categories:

```
enum PhysicsCategory:UInt32
{
    case edge = 1
    case ball = 2
}
```

Next, assign those categories to the edge and the balls. (Add the first two lines under sceneBody and insert the third line where you defined the other ball physics properties):

```
self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.edge.rawValue
self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ball.rawValue
ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ball.rawValue
```

And finally, check for collisions:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
   let firstBody = contact.bodyA
   let secondBody = contact.bodyB

   if firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.edge.rawValue && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.ball.rawValue || firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.ball.rawValue && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.edge.rawValue
   {
      if firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.ball.rawValue {
         firstBody.node?.removeFromParent()
         } else {
         secondBody.node?.removeFromParent()
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response, and it covered mostly what I am looking for. I was just wondering why the didBeginContact function doesn't seem to be called on a collision in Swift 3. I put a print statement in there, and it isn't being called at all when the balls are dropping, which is an issue. Any ideas on how to fix this, or what the new didBeginContact function is in Swift 3?

Comment: didBeginContact is part of an iOS framework so it should work as always. Everything should collide with everything by default, but there is a collision bit mask you could try setting: ball.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.edge.rawValue

Comment: Yeah, I did that exact thing, yet to no success. I figured out that I needed to add the SKPhysicsContactDelegate. The new Swift 3 function for that is didBegin: 'func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        
    }' This function I believe is the new Swift function for didBeginContact, and it is still not being called on the contact between the scene wall and the balls. I will create a GitHub repo and link you to it, if you would be willing to download it and see the problem.

Comment: I will update my answer to include the SKPhysicsContactDelegate. (Small oversight on my part, sorry!)  Before Swift 3, the first parameter of methods was in the name of the method itself. Starting with Swift 3, however, all labels are required, so you will see a lot of method names change just like didBegin(_contact:)

Comment: Sorry to keep you busy, but I changed all of the things that you suggested, and pushed them to Github, and it still doesn't seem to call any of the didBegin methods when a collision occurs, which would make my game extremely laggy if the nodes were just falling continuously. If possible, could you look at Github to try and identify the problem (In MainMenuScene.swift)? I really appreciate your help. https://github.com/GallantMorgan/ballz-ios-app

Comment: I added one more small, but very important detail to my answer: self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ball.rawValue  If you don't set the contactTestBitMask, you don't get notified. And that should do it!